# From SQLite to Parse.com

Tags: ios, sqlite, parse-platform

I'd like to migrate my app from using local SQLite to Parse.

I'm guessing that the best way to get started would be to build a migration mechanism that transfers current user data from the SQLite database to Parse. Are there any in built mechanisms for doing this?

Something else I'm not sure about: Because we'd like the app to function for users who choose to create an account and for users who choose not to (and also while no network connection) does it make sense to (a) enable local data store and (b) make all saving calls to saveEventually? From what I can tell reading the docs, saveEventually will save (pin) the data to the local data store until saving to the server is possible.

Another question is: if a user starts off using the app offline (chooses not to make an account) but later decides to signUp is it possible to then associate all previous data created while operating offline with their new account? For example, say Joe downloads the app and chooses not to signUp, and uses the app offline for 6 months. Then Joe realizes he needs to get a new device so he decides to signUp to preserve his data. When he signs up will the data he created over that 6 month period now be associated with his new account?

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this question we've devised a plan. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

What we plan to do is: (a) migrate our sqlite db into the parse local datastore (pin). We will not be using `saveEventually`, but instead use `pinInBackground:`, pinning all objects to a specific group and setting a flag `isDraft` (or something similar) to true. This flag then later allows us to access those objects that still need to be synced to parse.com. Then when the app is closed we'll kick off a background task in the app, pulling those pinned objects from that group that are still drafts, setting their `isDraft` flag to false, and then sending them up to parse.com. If an error occurs saving them, reset the `isDraft` flag to true so that on the next sync attempt we try again with that object.

We derived this migration from the [todos tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/using-the-local-datastore) provided by parse.com. I believe this will work. The only thing I'm concerned about is that we have over 15k users. If they all try to do this at the same time I'm fairly certain that we'll hit the api request ceiling (15k users * anywhere between 100 to 1000 db objects). However, this may not be a big issue since we'll be relying on the locally pinned objects on the client to populate the client, and when the client is notified of the overage error it will fail silently and the `isDraft` flag will be reset to true, ensuring that on the next app close the failing objects are tried again.

Anyone have a better solution? Or improvements to this one? I haven't been able to find much information on this process, but I'm sure others may be curious about it. We can't be the only ones trying to make this move.

Comment: unless someone can provide a better approach, I'm going to mark my answer as the correct. please feel free to add more information or provide a better solution.